# Função que retorne um array de strings que estiverem em todos os arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Fala gente, tudo bom?

Minha dúvida é simples, mas a solução talvez não seja TÃOOO simples assim.

A verdade é que estou realizando um trabalho em JS e em breve vou precisar resolver um problema que vai me fazer perder algumas horas quebrando a cabeça.

Então resolvi perguntar aqui no StackOverflow para adiantar um pouco da solução.

Vamos a problemática.

Suponha que eu tenha declarado 5 arrays, seguem:

```js
var objetos = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "adaga", "ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara", "zarabatana", "xilofone"];
var redondos = ["ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara"];
var cozinha = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "açucareiro", "xícara"];
var arma = ["adaga", "zarabatana"];
var musical = ["xilofone", "zabumba"]
```

Agora, eu preciso de uma função que quando eu passar 2 (ou mais) arrays, ela me retorne um novo array, contendo apenas as strings que estiverem presentes em TODOS os arrays que eu tiver passado.

**Exemplificando:**

Caso eu passe para a função os arrays: "objetos", "redondos" e "musical", o novo array que eu receber, deve conter apenas "zabumba".

Comment: Estranho que assim faz parecer que você deseja que façamos seu trabalho para não precisar fazê-lo quando for necessário. A solução é bem simples também, então irei aguardar você primeiro tentar fazer para somente depois ajudá-lo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu entendo sua visão, mas é que essa é só uma parte muito pequena de algo maior que estou fazendo e que eu sei que vou demorar um pouco até achar a solução mais otimizada, esse inclusive, é outro ponto que me faz vir aqui perguntar ao pessoal e ver as soluções e discutir, até chegar em uma mais otimizada.

Comment: Também te entendo e, particularmente, essas são as discussões que mais gosto aqui, porém sem você tentar fazer meio que seria apenas nós discutindo e você esperando a melhor solução, não? E por experiência própria, esse tempo que acha que levará até chegar em uma solução será exatamente o tempo que te fará entender l, de fato, a solução. Dica para quando for tentar: pense simples e faça o simples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom gente, segue a solução do problema:

```js
var objetos = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "adaga", "ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara", "zarabatana", "xilofone"];
var redondos = ["ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara"];
var cozinha = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "açucareiro", "xícara"];
var arma = ["adaga", "zarabatana"];
var musical = ["xilofone", "zabumba"]

var arrays = [objetos, redondos, musical];

var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
    return arrays.every(function(a) {
        return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result,null,4) + '</pre>');
```

Se alguém tiver uma solução melhor e quiser/puder compartilhar, agradeço!

Comment: Ao meu ver o SOpt vinga e vinga muito bem. Se quiser discutir algo relacionado a isso, te convido a entrar no [chat Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha). De qualquer forma, estarei removendo o comentário da resposta por não ter relação com o problema discutido.

Comment: Achei muito bom a combinação do `filter` com `every`, resolveu de forma simples um problema relativamente complexo. +1 Poderia explicar a lógica?

Comment: Com arrow function fica um pouco mais otimizado ainda, visualmente: https://jsfiddle.net/bvnwzamu/

Comment: hahah, é verdade @LucasCosta, é a mesma coisa, mas escrita de forma mais simples, assim dá pra deixar ela em uma linha só e não fica feio. Eu não tenho costume de usar arrows nos - poucos - scripts que eu faço. Valeu pelo complemento. Quanto a explicação da lógica vou comentar abaixo.

Comment: @LucasCosta respondendo a sua dúvida sobre a lógica utilizada, a parte mais difícil foi enxergar que eu não podia usar 3 arrays distindos para resolver o problema - até poderia, mas teria que usar muito mais linhas de código - quando eu me toquei que seria mais fácil usar um array contendo os arrays de string pra resolver tudo, foi meio que natural o restante da solução. A função shift ali no início, reserva um "segredo", quando você dá shift() em um array, o primeiro elemento daquele array será removido, MAS, a função retorna o elemento removido, que no caso, [...] (1/4)

Comment: [...]é o primeiro array dos 3 arrays do exemplo, e como eu quero apenas as palavras que estiverem em todos os arrays, não importa que array eu pegue (o ideal é pegar o que tiver menos elementos, mas abstrai isso aqui na pergunta). Continuando e sabendo que tanto faz o array que eu pegue, o filter() será dado em cima do array retornado pelo shift() e a função filter() vai ser a responsável por retornar um array contendo os elementos que passarem no teste, é só isso que ela faz, a função every() eu não lembro-me de ter usado nunca, foi um achado para mim, [...] (2/4)

Comment: [...]ela que faz a iteração elemento por elemento realizando a checagem que eu quiser, que no caso eu basicamente verifico: essa palavra (elemento) que está nesse array, também está nesse array principal (o array retornado pelo *shift()*, se estiver, retorne ela no *filter()* pelo - pouco - que entendo, é assim que o script se comporta @LucasCosta, tô longe de ser um especialista em JS e muito menos em otimização de código, mas gostei dessa solução final, [...] (3/4)

Comment: [...]acredito que ainda dê para otimizar alguma coisa, quando coloco um console.log() dentro do script é estranho, iterações demais ao meu ver, mas não consegui otimizar muito mais que isso e chegar ao resultado esperado. (4/4)

Answer (score 2):

Uma versão mais "manual" porque terá que iterar todos os itens do primeiro *array*.

**Exemplo**

```js
var objetos = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "adaga", "ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara", "zarabatana", "xilofone"];
var redondos = ["ábaco", "abajur", "abotoadura", "acetona", "açucareiro", "zabumba", "xícara"];
var cozinha = ["abridor de garrafa", "abridor de latas", "açucareiro", "xícara"];
var arma = ["adaga", "zarabatana"];
var musical = ["xilofone", "zabumba"];

function comuns(...arrays){

    let aux = 1,
        possui = false,
        npossui = false,
        novo = [];
        
    arrays[0].forEach(function(item){
       
       aux = 1;
       npossui = false;
       
       while (arrays[aux]){
          if (arrays[aux].indexOf(item) > -1) possui = true;
          else npossui = true;
          aux++;
       }
       
       if (possui && !npossui) novo.push(item);
    });
    
    return novo;
}

console.log(comuns(objetos,redondos,musical));
```